# Codeigniter combine two array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have problem to combining two array, here my sample code

```
$arr1 = [];
$data = $this->db->query("SELECT QUERY");

foreach ($data->result_array() as $row) {

$arr1[] = array(
   "type"                   => "column",
   "name"                   => $row['name'],
   "legendText"             => $row['name'],
   "showInLegend"           => true
);

}


$count = $this->db->query("SELECT QUERY");

foreach ($count->result_array() as $rows) {

$arr1[]["dataPoints"] = array(
   "label" => $rows['data']
);

}
```

With this code, result is

```
[
  {
    "type": "column",
    "name": "LA 1",
    "legendText": "LA 1",
    "showInLegend": true
  },
  {
    "dataPoints": {
      "label": "1"
    }
  }
]
```

I want to combine two array, So the output should be like this:

```
[
  {
    "type": "column",
    "name": "LA 1",
    "legendText": "LA 1",
    "showInLegend": true,
    "dataPoints": [{
      "label": "1"
    }]
  }
]
```

Please someone help me to find out the easiest way to solve this issue.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Not the best option for multidimensional arrays

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to fix this would be to change your database queries to one which would return all the information in a single query.

```
$data = $this->db->query("SELECT a.*, b.datapoints FROM table1 a, table2 b....");
```